# Python: Questions about math and negative power

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am trying to implement and algorithm and I am not sure how to implement in Python.

The algorithm is given as `[e ^ -ax] * [((e ^ by) - (e ^ -ax)) / ((e ^ by) + (e ^ -ax))]`

Where:

- `^` represents power of
- `e` is Euler's number with a value of `2.718`
- `a` and `b` are constants and given as `a = 0.2` and `b = 0.45`
- but `x` and `y` are variables where `a` and `b` will always be `>= 0`

This is what I have come up with but I am not sure if this is correct. It would be great if anyone can tell me if it's correct or is there an easier way to do this as it looks very complicated right now.

```
valueA = 0.2 * x
valueB = 0.45 * y

results = math.pow(math.e, -valueA) * (math.pow(math.e, valueB) - math.pow(math.e, -valueB)) / (math.pow(math.e, valueA) + math.pow(math.e, -valueB))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For computing *e*<sup>*x*</sup>, there's no need to write:

```
math.pow(math.e, x)
```

Instead, use [`math.exp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.exp) and write:

```
math.exp(x)
```

or:

```
from math import exp
exp(x)
```

Comment: Is it still the same if x is a negative value?

Comment: Yes. Try it and see for yourself, for example `print exp(-1), 1/e` → `0.367879441171 0.367879441171`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `**` operator:

```
In [48]: math.pow(2,10)
Out[48]: 1024.0

In [49]: 2**10              #replace the '2' by math.e or simply e
Out[49]: 1024
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of `math.pow` and replace `math.e` with just `e`:

```
from math import e
results = e**-valueA * (e**valueB - e**-valueA) / (e**valueB + e**-valueA)
```

You could also replace `valueA` with `ax` and `valueB` with `by` as well, to make things even simpler.